# MATLAB: Conditional summation

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays of the following form:

```
v1 = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... ]
c2 = { 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'c' 'c' 'c' 'c' ... }
```

(all values are examples only, no pattern can be assumed in the real data. `v1` and `c2` have the same size)

I want to obtain a vector containing the summation of the components of `v1` corresponding to equal values in `c2`. In the example above, the first component of the resulting vector would be `1+2+3`, the second `4+5`, and so on.

I know I can do it in a loop of the form:

```
uni_c2 = unique(c2);
result = zeros(size(uni_c2));
for i = 1:numel(uni_c2)
     result(i) = sum( v1(strcmp(uni_c2(i),c2)) );
end
```

Is there a single command or a vectorized way of doing the same operation?

Comment: "the summation of the components of v1 corresponding to equal values in c2". consecutive values in c2? For instance: v1 = [1 2 3 4], c2 = ['a','b','a','a'], what is the result you expect in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two lines:

```
[b, m, n] = unique(c2)
result = accumarray(n', v1)
```

The elements of result correspond to the strings in the cell array b.

Comment: Great, @Carl, exactly what I was looking for. The only issue is that, according to my test, `n` must be transposed to a column vector: `result = accumarray(n', v1)`. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I don't have Matlab at home, so I couldn't test my code. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is vectorized but a bad idea for very large vectors. For some problems a "vectorized" solution is worse than a `for` loop.

```
>> v1 = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
>> c2 = 'aaabbcccc'-'a'
c2 =
   0   0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2
>> N = repmat(c2',1,max(c2)-min(c2)+1) == repmat([min(c2):max(c2)],size(c2,2),1);
>> v1*N
ans =
    6    9   30
```

Comment: Very ingenious, @stardt! It's because of gems like this that I like vectorization questions on the web. But your solution uses the assumption that c2 follows the pattern in the question, when that was only a simplified example (as stated). In reality, the contents of my cell are a lot more complex and unpredictable. Any ideas on how to generalize your approach?

Comment: @jonnat The code does not depend on the pattern. It works with e.g. `c2 = 'abacaccbc'-'a'` What assumption does your real problem contradict?

Comment: my c2, in fact, contains elements that are nor single letters. I chose to use single letter elements as a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very general (and vectorized) solution is something like this:

```
v1 = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  ]
c2 = { 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'c' 'c' 'c' 'c'  }
uniqueValuesInC2 = unique(c2);
conditionalSumOfV1 = @(x)(sum(v1(strcmp(c2, x))));
result = cellfun(conditionalSumOfV1, uniqueValuesInC2)
```

Perhaps my solution needs a bit of an explanation to the untrained eye:

So first you actually need to compute the different possible values in `c2`, which is done by `unique`.

The `conditionalSumOfV1` function takes an argument `x`, it compares every element in `c2` with `x` and selects the corresponding elements in `v1` and sums them.

Finally `cellfun` is comparable to a `foreach` construct in some other languages: the function `conditionalSum` is evaluated for every value in the cell array you provide (in this case: every unique value in `c2`) and stores it in the output array. For other types of container variables (arrays, structs), MATLAB has equivalent `foreach`-like constructs: `arrayfun`, `structfun`.

This will work for contents of `c2` that are longer than a single character and it does not require a large `repmat` operation as stardt's solution. I do however have my doubts when it comes to long arrays where `c2` has only a few duplicate values., but I guess that will be a hard case for most algorithms. If you are in such a case, you might need to take a look at the extra outputs of `unique` or write your own alternative to `unique` (i.e. write `for` loops, preferably in a compiled language/MEX).